# Linq Entity Framework returning the value but not display

Tags: entity-framework, linq, blazor

Linq Entity Framework return the value but not displaying

```
mod = pron.Module.Include(x => x.Project).SingleOrDefault(x => x.ProjectId == id);
```

value get but not displaying

Comment: Because you have no html (cshtml).

Comment: Where you trying to display `mod` values?

Comment: In Razor Page value not displaying

Comment: Question is very incomplete.

Comment: if i use mod = pronto.Module.Find(id); value displaying if i use mod = pron.Module.Include(x => x.Project).SingleOrDefault(x => x.ProjectId == id); value not displaying

Comment: what is the difference between pronto and pron there? If ProjectId is in fact the PK, the data should be identical except the latter approach will also have Project data.

Comment: Pronto and pron are same only object name

Comment: Novfal.. Could you please provide more details about what you are trying to achieve? And a reproduce-able code?

Answer (score -1):

I do not really understand your question but I think you want somethink like

pron.Module.Where(x => x.ProjectId == id).Include(x => x.Project).FirstOrDefault();

Comment: Value getting from DB but not displaying  in form

Comment: `.Where()` and `.FirstOrDefault()` can  be merged. It's not clear why you think SingleOrDefault() is wrong.

Comment: if i use Where(x => x.ProjectId == id).Include(x => x.Project).FirstOrDefault(); value not getting from DB

Comment: @HenkHolterman is right, SingleOrDefault() is correct. The problem must be in the razor page. Can you show us more code?

Comment: <MatTable Items="project.Module" FilterByColumnName="ProjectName" PageSize="12">
  <MatTableHeader>
    <th>Module Name</th>    
  </MatTableHeader>
  <MatTableRow>
    <td>@context.ModuleName</td>
  </MatTableRow>
</MatTable>